# Equivalent for K9 content filter for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Are there alternative applications for K9 content filtering for ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Dan's guardian](http://dansguardian.org/) (available as a package in ubuntu repositories).

Dan's guardian may be installed as a [server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Servers/DansGuardian) or on a [single machine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DansGuardian). [Many](http://www.branchdistrictlibrary.org/professional/ubuntu_hardy_dg_page_01.php) [tutorials](http://www.pilpi.net/journal/item-985.php) [are](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=207008) available on how to configure it.

If you are searching for easier to configure, but less secure solutions as they will only filter firefox content, you might want to check these extensions:

- [ProCon Latte](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/1803)
- [brOOzi](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11595)

Another way to filter content would be to configure [SquidGuard](http://www.squidguard.org/) to [blacklist](http://urlblacklist.com/?sec=download) addresses.

Finally the best content filtering policy I know is to place the *child computer* in the living room and interact with the child during his/her browsing experience.

Comment: +1 for that last statement.  best policy, hands down.

Answer (score 1):

OpenDNS is great, but the IP address is not automatically updated and so you have to check it every day or two. There is software available to do this for Windows and Apple, but not Linux. I tried all the tweaks (scripts) but couldn't get them working.

Comment: See https://support.opendns.com/entries/23554765

Comment: It also easily by-passed.. Just change device settings to use 8.8.8.8, and on a different port to 53 if a simple port redirect is in use. Kids learn this stuff quicker than parents.

Answer (score 0):

An OS independent solution is [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/).

You set OpenDNS as your DNS provider and then can [configure it so that it won't return results for certain categories of sites](http://kimaso.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/Screenshot-OpenDNS-Dashboard-Settings-Content-Filtering-Google-Chrome.png). I use it and it works well.

Comment: Your link is expired